# how to set default link on active when entering site

Tags: jquery, html

See below my html code. I am using tab for my web application.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div><a href="#about" class="toggle">About</a></div>
    <div><a href="#photos" class="toggle">Photos</a></div>
    <div><a href="#rates" class="toggle">Rates and Reviews</a></div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6" id="detailsDiv" align="center" style="background-color:#CFF">
    <div id="about" >about</div>
    <div id="photos" style="display: none;">photos</div>
    <div id="rates" style="display: none;">Rates and Reviews</div>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code. When any user will click on site then always set my about tab.

```
$(function () {

    $('.toggle').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#mainDiv').find('a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $("#detailsDiv").children().hide(); 
        $(target).toggle();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `focus();` for that. Give an id (in this case let's say the id will be 'about') on the about anchor and do this next:

```js
$('#about').focus();
```

Use it outside of the click event.

And when the page loads the magic happens.

Comment: well, how implement sir

Comment: thanks, it fixed, just i add 'active' in about class

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#mainDiv').find('a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thanks, it fixed, just i add 'active' in about class

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
$(function () {

  // cache all togle class
  var all = $('.toggle');
  // get target for first element('about')
  var target = all.eq(0).attr('href');
  // add class the first element
  all.eq(0).addClass('active');
  // show target content
  $(target).show();

  $('.toggle').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#mainDiv').find('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#detailsDiv").children().hide(); 
    $(target).toggle();
  });
})
```